# What's the difference between Average Square Error and Mean Square Error ? Are they known for the same thin?

Tags: sas, prediction, mean-square-error

I have a bit of confusion regarding ASE and MSE as when I model my models in SAS Enterprise Miner, it shows these two measurement scales. What is the difference or similarity between the two and why are they both being displayed if they are similar. Example screenshot is shown below.
[image]

Comment: Hi!  This really belongs on [stats.se] - it's okay to ask questions about [tag:Enterprise-miner] here, but questions purely about statistics have a home there.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe ok thank you, i just posted there

Comment: Can you go ahead and delete this one then?  Thanks!